# What's more natural choice when talking about menstruation bleeding?

Tags: sentence-choice

What's the more natural choice when talking about the decrease in the menstruation flow?

> Today I have less blood.

or

> Today I'm less bleeding.

or

> Today the bleeding is decreased.

The first choice sounds to me a bit ridiculous since it also has a general meaning of less blood in the body, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: If you change "I'm less bleeding" to "I'm bleeding less", it seems fine. This seems to be the right way to qualify "-ing" verbs. Compare "The train was running fast" vs "The train was fast running"

Answer (score 7):

None of the OP's variants sound particularly idiomatic.
Speaking as a woman, menopausal, to express the idea that I was **bleeding less**, I used to say:

> **My period is lighter**
> My period is getting lighter

Comment: Thanks^+. Still, it's not clear to me whether you meant to say that your answer is regarding the menopausal period, or also works for the context of which a young woman on the 3rd or 4th day of menstruation, describes her condition and says that she has less secretion on that particular day because it's almost her end of the menstruation for that particular month, rather than the end of the menstruation ends in the menopause age.

Comment: @VirtuousLegend  It can be used for both situations but **I used to say** refers to when I had periods. P.S Don't use the word *secretion* for menstruation, you can use *less blood*,  or perhaps *less/slight discharge*.

Comment: Not a thing I ever remember talking about much, but perhaps _the flow is less/lighter today_.

Comment: @KateBunting   I don't think I ever used used the term *flow*,  perhaps it is a bit more  euphemistic than I prefer.

Comment: About the menstrual flow see https://www.thefreedictionary.com/menstrual+flow

Comment: @VirtuousLegend thanks but I was already familiar with the term. I just prefer the phrase  “a woman's / my *period*” rather than “a woman's / my *flow*” or the wordier "a woman's / my *menstrual flow*”

Answer (score 1):

Teens, especially those from urban areas like New York, often use a variety of slang and informal phrases. Here are some ways a teenager from New York might express that their menstrual bleeding has lessened:

> My flow is chill today.
> I'm spotting less today.
> It's not as heavy today.

Some more conversational ways to express that menstrual bleeding has lessened:

> My period isn't as heavy today.
> I'm not bleeding as much today.
> There's less bleeding today.
> It seems my cycle is lighter today.
> My flow has lessened today.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer ^+. Please, kindly refer to the examples I mentioned, whether they're normal or unnatural to the English native speaker. Thanks

Comment: All your examples are unnatural

Comment: I meant to ask him to refer to it in the answer itself, so I can choose it.

Comment: There are exactly [22 results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22flow+is+chill%22+today&sxsrf=AB5stBigUZJIeZPc6yJXTwV_uhi8fvGaLw:1690784359593&ei=Z1LHZNHWI8mN9u8P68KP2AI&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiRppTJpriAAxXJhv0HHWvhAysQ8tMDegQIBRAE&biw=1152&bih=632&dpr=2.5) for  "flow is chill (today)“ Only one refers to menstruation, and that is your answer here.

Comment: How does your googling contradict what i say? Big apple in 99% probably is just a big fruit and not NY. And?

Comment: It is relevant because this is an English language learner's site,  answers that include slang, phrases and idioms should be familiar with most anglophone speakers, not only to a group of NY teenagers.